# Мгновенные сообщения: собеседник печатает сообщение

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, comet

Сочувственно, хочу услышать возможные варианты реализации данной функции.

В данный момент реализован COMET-сервер на PHP + MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогично, как и отправка сообщения. Просто клиенту отправляется спецсообщение "ваш собеседник начал печатать".
А дальше, на стороне отправляемого запускается таймер и если за какой-то период времени (5 секунд) ничего не изменилось, отправляется сообщение "перестал печатать".

Comment: @KoVadim это верное и самое лучше решение.

Comment: Я примерно так и думал. Только вот что-то не додумал - как сообщать. Что на сервер отправлять и где хранить метку? В базе чтоль?

Comment: @exec если юзеров мало, то можно и оперативную задействовать

Comment: Наверное можно в memcached

Comment: Пока не настроен.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше используйте WebSocket, там как раз мгновенно всё и отправляется и можно так же вывести что собеседник печатает.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]